# Is a moon inside a hollow Earth possible?

Tags: planets, physics, moons, gravity, hollow-earth

The [Hollow Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Earth) theory is/was a pseudoscientific idea that our world is actually on the inside of a large sphere. The "sky" points inward towards the center, where the "Sun" (a light source) is, while the "ground" points outward.

Let's assume that we have a planet the size of Earth, except that it is a hollow Earth. In reality, it's simply an Earth-sized cavity inside a larger body, notably, some sort of artificial megastructure. I had assumed that said megastructure was spherical, but clearly I should have stated it explicitly, so I'll do so now. The structure will have spherical symmetry and be as uniform as possible.

Is it possible to put a moon inside the sphere - somewhere between the central light source and the "ground" - and have it move in an "orbit" around the center? Would the moon crash into the ground, or would it be stable?

I'm almost positive that the moon can't be as big as Earth's moon, but I don't know a reasonable size. I'm fine with anything bigger than, say, [Janus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus_(moon)) or [Epimetheus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimetheus_(moon)).

---

Bonus question (not necessary to answer): Is the setup possible if the hollow Earth is non-spherical, i.e. ellipsoidal?

Comment: [Related question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/hollow-planet-with-another-planet-inside-it), by the way.

Comment: Can't understand exactly _where_ the moon in question is being proposed to be put.

Comment: @YoustayIgo It's orbiting around the center, inside the sphere.

Comment: An in, a hollow earth with a moon in the center? Something like Edgar Rice Burroughs presented in his At The Earth's Core series?

Comment: @YoustayIgo Sort of near the center. I haven't read *At the Earth's Core*, though, so I don't know how similar the setups are.

Comment: Hmm. Since the answer would be too much opinion and factor based (too many ifs), I wouldn't venture to present an answer. I understand the perspective now. I already have some people not very pleased with my answers. I would say the whole thing depends on the thickness of the planet's crust. The thinner the crust, the lesser would be the chance of a gravitational crash and the higher the chances of sustaining a hollow spherical shape with a moon within. The inner space would still have to be filled with air though. I don't think perfect vacuum could exist in such a large cavity.

Comment: See [For the World Is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEB7O1K1ZXI).

Comment: Why are all the answers addressing the stability of the structure rather than answering the question?

Comment: @RomanReiner It's okay to challenge the premise of a question in some cases. I wish there was a focus more on analyzing the moon's orbit, but you can't do that if you don't know about the rest of the system. It is true, though, that some answers didn't discuss the moon, for potentially valid reasons.

Comment: See also the [Virga series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_of_Suns) where, yes, there is a large hollow sphere filled with air with structures inside (none *orbit* so much as get pushed by convection cells).

Comment: Do you want phases, like our Moon, or just some large sphere in the sky?

Comment: @Schwern Just a sphere in the sky. Phases seem like asking too much.

Comment: Is it bad, that all I can think about is that "night" will only come about by the moons constant eclipse of the sun?(obviously in different parts of the "world") This leads to the fact that some place will allways be in day. A more logical person that me might say that that place doesn't have a night and eclipses a just a regular occurrence :)

Comment: worth pointing out (though there are already a couple of answers to this effect). The inside of a spherical shell has 0 gravity iff the shell is of uniform density and thickness. We can't assume this is the case for this world (though it might be)

Comment: Zero gravity only exists at the exact center. Everything else experiences a net gravity - this is what could actually theoretically cause a hollow mega structure. But the moon would need to have enough gravity to hold itself together under a uniform spherical g force. It would have to be perfect- any shift would send it hurtling in the direction it shifted.

Comment: @SeanBoddy As is stated elsewhere, there is zero gravity everywhere in the cavity due to the shell theorem.

Comment: Cool - learned a thing today. So, then with no g-force gradient applied to the moon by the sphere - i believe that means nothing inherently keeps the moon centered in the shell? And persons inside the shell would track towards the moon. And possibly get squished by the shell. And standing outside the shell could get real weird when the net center of gravity shifted.

Comment: So it seems it could work provided that the shell and the moon each independently have a totally stable orbit around the system's star, since overall they don't seem to affect each other.

Comment: @SeanBoddy Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 18):

## No.

Bodies composed of known materials the size of the Earth and Moon are in ["hydrostatic equilibrium"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium),

> This occurs when external forces such as gravity are balanced by a
>   pressure gradient force.[1] For instance, the pressure-gradient force
>   prevents gravity from collapsing Earth's atmosphere into a thin, dense
>   shell, whereas gravity prevents the pressure gradient force from
>   diffusing the atmosphere into space.
>
> Hydrostatic equilibrium is the current distinguishing criterion
>   between dwarf planets and small Solar System bodies, and has other
>   roles in astrophysics and planetary geology. This qualification
>   typically means that the object is symmetrically rounded into a
>   spheroid or ellipsoid shape, where any irregular surface features are
>   due to a relatively thin solid crust. There are 31 observationally
>   confirmed such objects (apart from the Sun), sometimes called
>   planemos,[2] in the Solar System, seven more[3] that are virtually
>   certain, and a hundred or so more that are likely.

What this means in your case is that the strength of the materials is insufficient to support the mass above them.  So they flow like molten plastic/liquid and fill all voids.

So in your Scenario the "Earth" outer shell would collapse under its mutual gravitation.

The strength of materials required to prevent this from happening would be quite high and I don't have the time to perform the necessary calculations for you.

Comment: "Let's assume that we have a planet the size of Earth, except that it is a hollow Earth" - under this assumption (which was a part of the original question), of course it is possible. Let's not be distracted by trifles like non-existing materials :-) (after all, if we can discuss ringworlds...)

Comment: I think we have to assume whomever built this hollow Earth has the material science to hold it together. This is to allow the more interesting question of "well how do you explain the Moon"?

Comment: The theory generally held that there wasn't a shell, but a rigid substance which continued either infinitely or certainly for some considerable distance. Of course that has its own problems with gravity, but the theory rejected Newtonian models of gravity too (and Einsteinian even more so, often conflated with the people holding the theory being very often extremely anti-Semitic).

Comment: How is this any different from the idea of a dyson sphere? Those are considered plausible in many sci-fi settings, even though we certainly don't have the technology to build one today.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Very different - hollow planet is much more plausible, because you need *much* less building material and it needs to withstand *much* less stress.

Comment: @Ajedi32, Freeman Dyson originally envisioned his sphere as a spherical halo of orbiting bodies and not a single monolithic object.  Such a sphere of orbiting bodies could easily be built with modern technology provided enough time and money.

Comment: Also some recent conjectures are that it might make more sense to put a monolithic type Dyson Sphere around white dwarf type stars.  Place the sphere at a distance that provides 1 g of acceleration and the strength of materials constraints are (still fantastically large but) much more reasonable.

Comment: @RadovanGarabik, the problem is that *even if* you handwave away the strength of materials problems, you still have a stability problem with both designs (a solid shell Dyson Sphere or Moon inside the Earth).  A body inside a spherical shell is statically stable but dynamically unstable (ball at the top of the hill).  A tiny perturbation causes the inner body to crash into the shell unless active controls are used to maintain the configuration.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible without active intervention.

The sphere's gravity is zero on the inside.  So there is no force acting on the moon from the sphere.  This would allow the moon to orbit a mass at the center of the planet.

However any perturbation of the sphere would not be transmitted to the moon.  Hence nothing prevents the moon, and whatever it is that is in the center for the moon to orbit, to pick up velocity relative to the sphere.

Comment: What if the light source was fixed at the center, though, in relation to the sphere (as was sometimes used in hollow Earth theories)? Would that minimize the effects of motion of the outer sphere, because it would therefore impact the orbit of the moon?

Comment: +1 And things would get very complex if/when there are mountains on the planet and/or the moon.

Comment: @HDE226868 Yes, as long as the light source were sufficiently massive.

Comment: @HDE226868 I have absolutely no idea.  I would suppose it depends on the size of the hill sphere of the central body, although I am unsure about which body you should caculate that hill sphere in relation to.

Comment: Of course there would be gravity inside the sphere.  Gravity from the light source.  And if there was no gravity, the moon would not be able to orbit.  To orbit, you do not only need to "pick up velocity".  You also need a net force to cause acceleration - that velocity vector has to change in direction, at least, else it would not be an orbit, but an object traveling in straight line and eventually hitting the shell.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure it would no longer count as a moon.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus There's no gravity inside the sphere from the shell due to the shell theorem; see [Radovan's answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/27451/627).

Comment: Due to the shell, no, but if there is a light source at the center, that would create a gravitational field, and if you are going to have a moon inside the shell, you will need that gravitational field to be strong enough to accelerate the moon to produce orbital motion.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus All of that is assumed/stated in the answer.

Comment: <pedantic>Gravity would be 0 at the **center of the sphere**</pedantic>. If you go from Earth crust to the core, the gravity force weakens because you only need to consider the layers under you (if you are halfway travel, you are only affected by the gravity of the 3400 km sphere under you, the outer layers effect cancel themselves between the ones "under" you and the ones "over" you.

Comment: @SJuan76 It's a shell, so there's zero gravity *everywhere* inside the shell. Again, see the shell theorem.

Answer (score 8):

Certainly - [the sphere's gravity at the inside will be zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem), so the composition and thickness of the crust is irrelevant. The moon has to orbit the central light source, and the mass of the light source should be much bigger than the moon's, and you'd better keep vacuum in the cavity (since there is no gravity, you cannot expect the air to stick close to the crust). Other than that, it's possible.

Comment: A large, thick-crusted hollow sphere would tend to crush in itself due to gravity. That was the reason I stated that there should be air inside.

Comment: Thanks. I've used the shell theorem before, and I should have been able to figure that out. :P

Comment: +1 I was going to say it was impossible, but I'd forgotten about the mass of the light source. However, I wonder how big the both of them could get before their orbits of each other would end up slamming them into the walls (or each other).

Comment: You can't have the moon orbiting the light source if there is air in the cavity; air resistance will drain energy from the system until they collide.

Comment: The moon would soon become unstable, any amount of instability that shifts the moon ever so slightly will increase the pull between the moon and the outside on one side and decrease it on the other. This means that soon the moon will crash into the outer shell (or the other way around).

Comment: @Thijser Why would that be the case? The force of gravity at *any point* inside the sphere - not just the center - is zero.

Comment: Yes the gravity on the inside of a hollow sphere is indeed zero. However this is not a hollow sphere, there is a moon (or more likely a core) in there which has it's own gravity. Think of it this way if we where to paper shell around the earth we would not suddenly lose our gravity.

Comment: @Thijser The gravitational force due to the moon is immaterial here. The force of gravity on the moon due to the sphere is the same as the force on the sphere due to the moon.

Comment: The gravity inside the hollow sphere might not be zero, since the sphere is essentially a bubble inside of a larger structure. If you took a cube of molten iron a million miles to a side and blew a bubble the size of the Earth in one corner, the gravity would all be toward the structures center, not the spheres center. The only way the gravity at the center of the sphere is zero is if it is also the center of the structure. And the whole structure would need to be spinning really fast to get 1g in the spheres surface, which would crushing the further out in the structure you go.

Comment: You'd still have the problem that any deviation between the light source/moon barycenter's velocity and the shell's velocity wouldn't self-correct, so eventually they'd impact. But it would be reasonably stable for a while.

Answer (score 2):

**Not without artificial gravity or some other outside source.**
Your mega structure large enough to have an earth sized pocket is going to have a lot of mass. Something that big is going to need futuristic materials and technologies to keep from collapsing.

Anything on the inside of the sphere is going to be drawn toward the center of the structure. If the sphere is off center then everything will be pulled toward one side. If it's in the center of the structure then things would just fall off the surface toward the "sky", unless...
To get gravity on the inside surface of a sphere without artificial gravity it needs to be spinning, meaning the structure needs to be spinning around the sphere, or a mechanism needs to be spinning the earth size sphere independently of the structure.

Spinning the whole structure is not a good idea, since if you have 1g at the surface of the sphere, you'll have even more the further out you go.

Angular Velocity: 0.0118 rotations/minute

Earth Radius: 3959 miles
Gravities: 1g

Radius: 5000 miles
Gravities: 1.26g

Radius: 8000 miles
Gravities: 2g

Stress on the structure would be increased exponentially the further out from the center of gravity you get.

If you just spin the sphere independently you still need super materials like [ringworld scrith](http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/Scrith) and you better hope it's really well balanced.

So you'll have to pick your magic: Artificial gravity or impossible building materials.

Edit:
Without artificial gravity you'd need a gravity point source in the center to orbit a moon around, since centripetal force wouldn't work to orbit inside a sphere.

Any variations in mass in the outside structure would tend to destablize the system, similar to the three body problem, requiring constant corrections to keep the moon from crashing.

**With artificial gravity, getting a moon to do anything you want is easy.**

Comment: This is thorough, but doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: @HDE226868 You're right! I got caught up in the rest of it and forgot my original point. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere). It is theoretically possible to still have orbital bodies inside the sphere in their orbit around the sun. Assuming we live on the inside of the Dyson shell and can process the entirety of the sun's output without frying, we wouldn't have a moon since the only orbital bodies are the planets further in and the Sun. There's no center of gravity for a moon to orbit around, since the Dyson sphere's center of gravity is the sun itself. That doesn't stop the Venus or Mercury from having moons of their own.

Comment: My concept is similar to a Dyson Sphere but is obviously not identical, being Earth-sized. As such, planets aren't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your bonus question: If the hollow earth is oblate or prolate spheroidal, and the two body system of moon and light source remains in the plane on which the cross section of the hollow earth is still circular, then stable orbits will exist as they would otherwise by symmetry. For a more complicated case, I expect nothing but a series of rather intense numerical simulations could determine the answer to whether there exist any periodic orbits at all.

Comment: I think you might not have finished the second sentence: *If the hollow earth is oblate or prolate spheroidal, and the two body system of moon and light source remains in the plane on which the cross section of the hollow earth is still circular* . . . then?

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks, getting ahead of myself.

Comment: Great, thanks. Would there still be gravity inside the sphere, though - in other words, does the result of the shell theorem still hold?

Comment: the shell theorem would not hold. There would be a gravitational field attracting toward the narrowest parts of the shell. But in the plane I have described, there would still be zero gravity, which is why this works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need:

- a *very* dense central light source, and this density is in contrast with what we know about sufficiently powerful energy sources, i.e. nuclear fusion. Of course you could go with an artificial light source, such as a degenerate matter sphere which reflects light beamed from the inside of the shell.
- some next-to-uncompressible material with which to build the shell, *or* some mechanical means of counteracting the gravity of the inner sphere and preventing it from making the outer shell collapse (the late [Paul Birch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Birch_%28writer%29) suggested a network of rails where heavy carriages would travel at orbital velocities, thus exterting an outward pressure capable of counteracting gravity. Of course, this leaves us with the problem of energizing the network itself.
- some way of keeping the outer shell centered on the light source. The net force exerted by the shell on the central sphere would be zero, which means there's nothing to stop small perturbations to make the central sphere drift against the shell (it's the same reason Niven's Ringworld has stabilizing engines)
- the internal volume should be kept in vacuum, or the Moon's orbit would quickly degrade.

If the perturbations are small enough, it could be feasible to stabilize the shell (and maybe the moon too) using the pressure of the light being beamed from the shell to the "Sun".

However, the central volume would be uninhabitable, as gravity would push towards the "Sun" and the whole cavity would be in vacuum. People on the inside of the shell would need to receive light through thick, airtight glass floors.

Answer (score -1):

A mass at the centre and a uniform superstructure of sufficient mass such that the gravitational attraction on any body between the central mass and the superstructure by the central mass equal the attraction due to the superstructure in that direction. There's your answer. ;)

Think of gravity as a set of elastic ropes. The one rope pulling a "moon" towards the central must be balanced by ropes extending from the superstructure in every direction. Calculating these forces will be an infinite series, as the rest of the superstructure will also exert a gravitational attraction towards a moon in between. It is doable, but obviously nothing could live there, unless you build a set of biospheres along the superstructure.

Tidal forces will be a major concern, as will Coriolis forces is the superstructure is spinning. The poles might be liveable; the equator, between the moon-based tides and the structure's own spin, would be like the inside of a washing machine.

Comment: Um... you mean it would be silvery and riddled with holes?

Comment: @Burki: No, I mean Turbo-Clean (tm) with cyclone wash (r) and 6-motion direct drive(c) :P

Comment: Just to clarify in case my last comment wasn't obvious: the superstructure's rotation would create angular momentum outwards, resulting in liquid being forced towards the poles. The [slip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor#Slip) caused by the "moon" would create a current going the other way, but perpendicular to the other. The result would be the kind of turbulence you'd expect inside a good washing machine.

Comment: It ws clear (to me), but i simply couldn't resist :-)

Comment: It's no fun to have to explain a joke ;)