# Planet that allows subterranean orbits

Tags: science-based, planets, orbital-mechanics

Would it be possible for a planet to have a geometry that allows relatively stable orbits beneath the surface? I understand an artificial object could achieve this just fine, given the technology, but could a naturally formed planet either have the structure to allow for this or be carved out in such a way that it remains stable while allowing this?

By "relatively stable orbit" I don't mean a circular one nor one that doesn't require periodic corrections, simply one that could count as stable enough that a modern satellite could use its thrusters to correct it for its operational lifetime (10-20 years).

Obviously this would require the planet to lack an atmosphere. However, I'm wondering if specifically, an atmosphere-less planet with a vast subterranean cave that spans its underground would allow for this. Would it require rocky columns? If there was no physical connection between the underground and surface would it hold together?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have discussed this earlier, but the punchline is that no, it can't work; there's too much mass involved, so you can't make the sphere hollow (the sphere will collapse in on itself), and thus there's no way to have anything on the "inside" of the surface simply because even if it could form in the first place, there won't be any "inside" for long enough for it to matter.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Hmm, do you mean [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27449/is-a-moon-inside-a-hollow-earth-possible)? Seems like it's pretty conclusive. Should I just delete this or flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: @ivy_lynx, in this case we're talking about an artificial satellite of a natural world. Different question.

Comment: [This](http://www.idlewords.com/2007/04/the_alameda-weehawken_burrito_tunnel.htm) seems strangely appropriate.

Comment: @ivy_lynx Yes, that looks like the question I had in mind. I can close this as a duplicate if you want? I think having this as a sign post serves a useful purpose, since the terms used are reasonable in both but different between the two; it helps searching. (The fact that one asks about an artificial satellite and the other asks about a natural satellite is IMO not a large enough difference to warrant having two questions that cover essentially the same ground; no pun intended.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes that seems ideal, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - even if you managed to make your shell planet, the net gravity inside a hollow sphere is **zero** at all points in the interior. So your inner planet would be rattling around rather than orbiting.

Comment: @Oldcat Well, MichaelKjörling hasn't made any such statement. If your comment is addressed to me however, I have to correct you. The [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) that you're basing your argument on doesn't state that the shell shields the interior from gravity, but that it itself will not exert a _net force_ upon objects in the interior. This means the inner planet would still orbit just fine, as long as both itself and the shell either used to be part of the same orbiting mass or were formed this way. The planet still experiences gravity from the star.

Comment: @Oldcat Whether the answer is "yes, it's possible if you do it *like this*" or "no, that's not possible according to currently known scientific laws because *that*" doesn't change the answer to "are answers to *this question* equally applicable to *that question*?", the latter of which being what duplicate-ness is about.

Comment: @ivy_lynx - orbiting **what?**  there's nothing inside the shell exerting forces on it.

Comment: @Oldcat Orbiting the same star (or body) the shell is orbiting. Just because the shell doesn't exert a force, doesn't mean nothing else does. If such a shell was a gravitational shield, we could just use spheres for anti-gravity.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an artifician canyon or artificial cavern. Something like that features in one of the [Culture](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheCulture) stories by Iain M. Banks. A natural canyon or cavern with the same geometry would be extremely unlikely.